# Mass update all cells in a column with a substring of it's original value

Tags: mysql, mariadb, update, substring

I need to trim the last seven characters off of all the cells in a column.

This query returns the results that I need

```
SELECT test_date, SUBSTRING(test_date FROM 1 FOR CHAR_LENGTH(test_date) - 7) as test from results;
```

I now need to take the computed result from the substring and replace the original values.

Here's what the data looks like, if it helps.

[image: Data Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a simple Update

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>     (`test_date` datetime)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Table1
>     (`test_date`)
> VALUES
>     ('2020-06-10 00:06:17.185449'),
>     ('2020-06-10 00:11:05.943217'),
>     ('2020-06-10 00:13:45.375109'),
>     ('2020-06-10 00:13:45.461321'),
>     ('2020-06-10 00:15:32.497548'),
>     ('2020-06-10 00:15:32.544873')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE Table1 SET test_date = SUBSTRING(test_date FROM 1 FOR CHAR_LENGTH(test_date) - 7)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROm Table1
> ```
>
> ```
> | test_date           |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2020-06-10 00:00:00 |
> | 2020-06-10 00:00:00 |
> | 2020-06-10 00:00:00 |
> | 2020-06-10 00:00:00 |
> | 2020-06-10 00:00:00 |
> | 2020-06-10 00:00:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a7251c9dbbfee7270dae1f1a713ccaa)*

Comment: please [accept it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Hey sorry! I thought I had, thanks for the prompt :)